# Parsing a MySQL log file in Java

Tags: java, mysql, parsing

I have a MySQL log file that has all sorts of information on each file (When a connection was made, when a query was made, when the connection was ended etc.) I have to parse the log file so I can take the data on each line, put it in an array, then do some calculation based on it.

Here is a sample from the log file:

```
151011 12:52:51       1 Connect     user@127.0.0.1 on testdb
              1 Query       SHOW SESSION VARIABLES
              1 Query       SHOW COLLATION
              1 Query       SET character_set_results = NULL
              1 Query       SET autocommit=1
              1 Query       SELECT q1,q2 FROM q_table
              1 Query       SELECT s1,s2 FROM s_table
              1 Query       select count(*) as c from i_table WHERE val = 1
              1 Query       select count(*) as c from k_table WHERE cid = 1
              1 Query       SELECT name,age FROM i_table WHERE ck = 1
151011 12:52:54       1 Query       SELECT name,aid FROM j_table WHERE co = 1
151011 12:52:59       1 Query       SELECT * from values where lastname='smith'
```

Unfortunately the spaces in the line are not separated by a tab character ("\t"). Worse, some lines have additional date and time at the beginning while some don't. Which means some lines have more data to parse than others. How would I parse this log file?

So far, I had the following:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("data.log"));
ln = scan.nextLine();
ar = ln.split("\t");
System.out.println(ar[0]);
System.out.println(ar[1]);
```

But that prints the following line, for example:

```
151018 12:52:51                              // First slot in the array
      1 Connect     user@127.0.0.1 on tested // Second slot in the array
```

Is there any way to do this? Or is just not possible?

Comment: "Unfortunately the spaces in the line are not separated by a tab character ("\t")" What does that mean?

Comment: Just use `\s` it matches all spacing characters.

Comment: It would have been much easier if each element in the line had a common separator between them. For example, the date, then a tab space, then action, then tab space...so on. However, here it's all in spaces.

Comment: I would parse the grammar, and ignore the whitespace. Looks to me like the specific indents are not significant

Comment: @JonnyHenly That would not work. It would match every space character, including the ones inside the queries. I would like to keep the query as a whole, rather than separating every word into an array index.

Comment: I think you want to parse the data. That's the goal. The rest is [X/Y problematic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me you want to do a regex with the following groups separated by whitespace:

1. the date specific regex (this group is optional)
2. a number
3. either "Connect", "Query", or any string that would be in the same place
4. a group that starts with non-whitespace and continues with anything

   ```
   String dateTime, number, type, message;
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
       "(\\d{6} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2})?\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(Connect|Query)\\s+([^\\s].*)");
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ln);

   if (matcher.matches()) {
       dateTime = matcher.group(1);//this will be null if no date
       number = matcher.group(2);
       type = matcher.group(3);
       message = matcher.group(4);
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. The problem being broken down like that helps significantly. I'll try my best.

Comment: Great feel free to up vote and or select the answer. :) @DemCodeLines

Comment: Note that this log is notoriously poorly designed for parsing.  For example, if the query has newlines in it, a single query will actually span multiple lines.  A much better idea is to use the "slow query log," setting the minimum time to 0 (so that all queries are considered "slow," and thus all queries will be logged). Its format is more machine-readable, and it gives you much better info, like rows examined vs rows returned.

Comment: @DemCodeLines I added an example